# How to completely remove flatpak

Tags: apt, uninstall, flatpak

I have removed flatpak with `sudo apt-get purge flatpak`; however, if I run `locate flatpak` I find several files and several directories. Can I remove them all with `rm -r` or there is a "better" way? If so, how do I have to do that?

### Edit

Since my output is 21909 rows long and, as @mook765 noted, nobody will ever be so crazy to read them all I think I should reformulate the question as follows: **if I had a normal installation of *flatpak*, what would be the best way to remove it and all its files and folders?**

Comment: Nope, your way will work fine.

Comment: You shouldn't do that! Without seeing the output of your command `locate flatpak` it's impossible to give better advice.

Comment: Do I have to add the full output of the command? It is 21909 rows. Note that I just want to remove every file and directory left by flatpak...

Comment: That's a lot. Remove them on your own risk. No one of us will go through 21909 rows of output...

Answer (score 32):

I'm assuming you didn't uninstall the run times that flatpak applications require. I would recommend reinstalling flatpak and running the following commands:

```
flatpak uninstall --unused

sudo apt-get remove --autoremove flatpak

sudo apt-get purge flatpak
```

This should erase the majority of the files left behind from flatpak. I had around 4000 after trying it out. I decided it wasn't for me and had to look for a few hours to find a way to remove the majority of the files. These three commands had reduced nearly 4000 files that dealt with flatpak to 197.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `flatpak uninstall --all`

Answer (score 22):

*Flatpak* applications and runtimes aren't removed when you uninstall the `flatpak` package using `apt`.

I'd rather reinstall `flatpak`, use it to remove any leftover *Flatpak* packages, and then purge it. On Ubuntu 20.04 Focal:

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak uninstall --all
sudo apt purge --autoremove flatpak
```

You can look at `/var/lib/flatpak/` to check that everything has been removed. You may also need to reboot or logout/login to update application launchers.

Comment: If apps [were installed](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-command-reference.html#flatpak-installation) at user space, some files could be on `~/.local/share/flatpak` (immutable) and `~/.var/app/` (config)

Comment: flatpak uninstall --all results in `unknown option -all` The above answer worked for me

Comment: The command should probably be `flatpack-uninstall --all`. Check the `man flatpack-uninstall` command for details.