# What is /home/me/.local/share/flatpak and how to remove it?

Tags: 20.04, disk-usage, shared-folders, cleanup, flatpak

I have a pretty small Ubuntu 20 LTE install. It is essential that it is small, however fully functional with LibreOffice, Thunderbird, etc.

I have noticed recently that /home/me/.local/share/flatpak uses nearly 1 GB of data, however I have no Flatpak apps installed:

```
$ pwd
/home/me/.local/share/flatpak/repo/objects
$ du -s *
112 00
92  01
108 02
12696   03
44  04
92  05
28  06
184 07
96  08
11680   09
48  0a
180 0b
68  0c
108 0d
136 0e
96  0f
11548   10
76  11
64  12
160 13
12156   14
72  15
100 16
80  17
11580   18
80  19
92  1a
56  1b
13036   1c
116 1d
56  1e
92  1f
64  20
76  21
84  22
52  23
96  24
52  25
60  26
72  27
11628   28
11364   29
32  2a
188 2b
100 2c
12972   2d
52  2e
160 2f
120 30
104 31
88  32
108 33
25364   34
108 35
96  36
96  37
124 38
32  39
92  3a
116 3b
56  3c
76  3d
184 3e
12892   3f
180 40
120 41
160 42
108 43
13040   44
11700   45
124 46
56  47
88  48
48  49
168 4a
128 4b
11904   4c
20  4d
164 4e
72  4f
108 50
11676   51
11264   52
32  53
80  54
84  55
48  56
56  57
124 58
64  59
68  5a
11852   5b
40  5c
56  5d
60  5e
84  5f
11344   60
108 61
68  62
64  63
25080   64
152 65
36  66
80  67
88  68
60  69
200 6a
24  6b
72  6c
176 6d
52  6e
120 6f
13048   70
12208   71
11612   72
48  73
44  74
44  75
13044   76
96  77
124 78
132 79
96  7a
108 7b
132 7c
11416   7d
80  7e
64  7f
112 80
72  81
64  82
52  83
124 84
160 85
36  86
11360   87
172 88
92  89
12684   8a
76  8b
72  8c
116 8d
80  8e
68  8f
116 90
132 91
96  92
92  93
68  94
76  95
52  96
80  97
164 98
120 99
48  9a
11932   9b
56  9c
11616   9d
72  9e
80  9f
84  a0
108 a1
11252   a2
92  a3
60  a4
88  a5
36440   a6
56  a7
12004   a8
12192   a9
72  aa
60  ab
84  ac
48  ad
108 ae
40  af
48  b0
56  b1
44  b2
44  b3
11700   b4
11420   b5
24  b6
11344   b7
88  b8
64  b9
56  ba
56  bb
56  bc
36  bd
116 be
68  bf
160 c0
48  c1
48  c2
56  c3
32  c4
12056   c5
44  c6
128 c7
124 c8
76  c9
12044   ca
84  cb
13072   cc
176 cd
128 ce
76  cf
152 d0
160 d1
96  d2
172 d3
88  d4
124 d5
116 d6
80  d7
96  d8
100 d9
164 da
76  db
76  dc
48  dd
60  de
88  df
60  e0
128 e1
76  e2
48  e3
68  e4
92  e5
48  e6
100 e7
40  e8
56  e9
13184   ea
60  eb
32  ec
12760   ed
13008   ee
11552   ef
64  f0
164 f1
36220   f2
12884   f3
136 f4
11704   f5
32  f6
13004   f7
112 f8
12996   f9
144 fa
11652   fb
12936   fc
144 fd
116 fe
48  ff
$ flatpak list
$
```

If so what is stored there and how to safely remove its content?

Comment: Only 51 kB for me. I have plenty of flatpaks. Take a look what is taking space under that folder. If you do not have any flatpak installed, it is safe to delete that folder.

Comment: [How to completely remove flatpak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174596/how-to-completely-remove-flatpak)

Comment: I have updated the question with disk usage. Apparently there are some flatpaks there. Does flatpak has something to do with Gnome or Snap?

Comment: No. Flatpak, Gnome, and Snap are all unrelated to each other